# How to get all the objects in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsarray

I'm using core data and just made a "Data" entity. It only has one attribute which is "text". I want to store all my data in an array that I called myDataArray. In my viewDidAppear I have:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Data"];


myDataArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
```

I used to be able to do

```
NSManagedObject *DataObject = [myDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

when I was working with table views, but this is a different scenario. How can I get all the objects in this array and display them on a label?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to fetch all objects inside fetchedResultsController:

```
NSArray * myDataArray = [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

**Updated: Fetch all objects without fetchResultsController:**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```